Sending HTTP Node.js Requests vs Browsers Requests, where is the difference?
When I try to send a request to a certain API with my own code in Node.js, I receive a "detection" of unusual usage of their API.
They call it a "VPN/Proxy detection" and returns status code 403 Forbidden.
This detection is only effective when I make my HTTP requests via my own code or I have noticed the same phenomenon when I use an intermediary like Burp Suite.
Why is this and how to fix it?
I have tested the VS Code Extension "Thunder Client" and it seems that the "VPN/Proxy detection" isn't effective on this extension (or maybe on VS Code extensions). I can't understand because, by verifying with tools like Requestly.io, the headers ARE THE SAME.
I also discovered that once I turn protocol from "HTTP/1.1" to "HTTP/2", my extension is now detected by the "VPN and Proxy Detector". But my code in Node.js uses "HTTP/1.1" so maybe it is using the "HTTP/2" which force the detector to consider you as a "BOT" but that's not really relevant in my case.
I've seen that, when I open my extension "Thunder Client" and that there is a problem with my internet connexion, it shows Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies: ["SOCKS 127.0.0.1:23321"] which maybe indicates that Thunder Client uses SOCKS which maybe let the request bypass the detector ?
Also, when I try to use Requestly.io to watch my request by proxying my requests, the requests passed by the extension doesn't works anymore (all are detected as "UNAUTHORIZED_PROXY"). But if this time I choose to leave Requestly.io, my extension shows me Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies: ["PROXY 127.0.0.1:8281"]
When I pass my requests on my web Browser (Firefox) on the website I use with the SAME code as I use for Node.js, the requests are not "DETECTED" but once I use Requestly.io to pass all my requests into a self-proxy, requests are "detected" (on Firefox) as "unauthorized requests".
Maybe the SOCKS can bypass verification for the request ? And I have heard about Certificates of Authority, does them play a role in this ? Maybe my extension, by passing all the requests on a SOCKS simulate a "real connection" to the service ?
Here is an example of my code :
const req = await fetch("https://mywebsite.com/", {
    headers: {
    "Connection": "close", // I also tried keep-alive
    "Accept-encoding": "gzip",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer MyToken"
   }
})
const response = await req.json()
console.log(response) // 403 Forbidden

Thank you in advance for helping me.
I tried different nodejs libraries : axios, fetch (native), node-fetch, request
There is no difference.
I also tried to switch on "HTTP" protocol but it doesn't works.

At least please show request and response headers in case of browser and Node.js (there should be difference at least in user-agent and other headers) in the post

Does the API perhaps implement special checks like in this case?
